# Beginner trying to learn python

Tags: python

When I run my code and guess the right number, the code doesn't work and says *try again*.
How do I fix it?

```py
import random   
   
number = random.randint(1,10)

print("Please enter your number down below")

yourguess = input()


if number == yourguess:

  print("You guessed it") 

else:

  print("Try again")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It'd be great if you could change the title of your question to describe your problem. Also, note that you're working with random numbers here - how do you know you really guessed the right number?

Comment: You are comparing an int to a string. `if str(number) == yourguess:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to compare strings, or compare numbers. I suggest turning the input into an integer like this:

```py
import random   
   
number = random.randint(1,10)

yourguess = int(input("Please enter your number: "))


if number == yourguess:

  print("You guessed it") 

else:

  print("Try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Input` defaults to string, you need to change it to int to be comparable. Other than that your code is fine.

```
import random   
   
number = random.randint(1,10)

print("Please enter your number down below")

yourguess = input()
yourguess = int(yourguess)

if number == yourguess:

  print("You guessed it") 

else:

  print("Try again")
```